# How to send a single request through p:commandButton inside p:dialog?

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I am using [PrimeFaces Schedule](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml). I have noticed that after you [select a slot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lkvr4.png)

[image: select a slot]

"save" button can be clicked multiple times, depends on how fast you can click. I did it 5 times before dialog disappeared.

[image: N]

Please find below the code snippet copied from the same [link](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/schedule.xhtml):

```
<p:dialog widgetVar="eventDialog" header="Event Details" showEffect="clip" hideEffect="clip">
    <h:panelGrid id="eventDetails" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="title" value="Titles:" />
        <p:inputText id="title" value="#{scheduleView.event.title}" required="true" />

        <p:outputLabel for="from" value="From:" />
        <p:calendar id="from" value="#{scheduleView.event.startDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="to" value="To:" />
        <p:calendar id="to" value="#{scheduleView.event.endDate}" timeZone="GMT+2" pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"/>

        <p:outputLabel for="allDay" value="All Day:" />
        <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="allDay" value="#{scheduleView.event.allDay}" />

        <p:commandButton type="reset" value="Reset" />
        <p:commandButton id="addButton" value="Save" actionListener="#{scheduleView.addEvent}" oncomplete="PF('myschedule').update();PF('eventDialog').hide();" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</p:dialog>
```

Problem is how to restrict number of request to 1 per dialog box.

Thanks

Comment: The dialog is irrelevant. Please note that PrimeFaces / JSF simply renders HTML. You can prevent multiple clicks the same way as you would in HTML.

Comment: You are right PrimeFaces / JSF simply renders HTML. Adding onclick="this.disabled=true" solves the problem.

Comment: Thanks @JasperdeVries